# Assign Workflow Task To Related User

Tags: workflow

When building Approval Workflows it is possible to create a Task say, when the process is started. I thought it would be good to assign the Task to the approver but SalesForce only offers you a (more or less) static User/Role selection lookup. I have the Approver as a custom field (`Approver__c`) on the object being approved - how to assign the task to that `Approver__c` person?

Answer (score 1):

The approval will show in the Items to approve section for the approver (if you've added into their home page layout). Also an email goes out using the template you've specified.

If you additionally want to assign a task, don't reckon that's possible via workflow which expects a named user. Unless they're on the account or opportunity team https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_tasks.htm

Your other alternative is a field update which you use to invoke an apex trigger which can assign that task using your approver__c lookup

Comment: What I was aiming at was (similar to the standard "Items to Approve" feature of Contracts) that the Approver has an overview of all the items they need to approve. With Contracts they get a task in the Tasks section of the Home page.